# Flash file select dialog limitation in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, uploadify, flash, plupload

I'm trying to integrate a JavaScript multiple file uploader into a website. I've worked with `Uploadify` before and wanted to go with that. The difference in this case was that I needed to allow a large number of files in the upload queue (up to 500).

Everything works fine in `Firefox`, `IE6-9` and `Safari`. Except for `Chrome`, where when selecting more than 232 files at once (using the Flash file select dialog) it doesn't do anything (the file select event is not triggered for the JS script to capture).

At first I thought it was an `Uploadify` bug, and decided to try `Plupload` as an alternative. Problem is that I hit the same dead end with the Flash version of Plupload, it just won't do anything when selecting more than 232 files at once.

Is this a known Flash Player limitation/bug in Chrome?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Bogdan, could you answer this question please. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255101/laravel-query-to-get-results-having-at-least-one-element-of-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug related to this:
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASL-299

Comment: It seems the bug report link you posted, is indeed for the same case I'm facing. I made some changes to the uploadify swf component, and added an event listener for the cancel event and it does triggers that instead of select like it should. Thanks a lot for your help