# Laravel query to get results having at least one element of an array?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have `posts` and `postWriters` tables with one-to-many relationships. (I have also `writers` table).

Each post has been written by several writers collaboratively.

I want to get first 20 posts which have been written by at least one writer I follow.

For example the writers that I follow:

```
$arrayOfWriterIds_IFollow = [3, 5, 123, 45, ..., 3456] // total 100 ids
```

The query:

```
$posts = Post::where(
    array( 'postWriters' => function($l) {
        $l->whereIn('writer_id', $arrayOfWriterIds_IFollow); // or array(3, 5) for 2 writers..
    })
)
->orderBy('submitTimestamp', 'desc')
->take(20)
->get();
```

The query does not work.

Is this approach appropriate or should I add a dedicated table to evaluate my results?

Comment: How do you follow a writer?

Comment: I have some tables, one of them is followings table. I get _$arrayOfWriterIds_IFollow_ from this table.

Comment: display your db structure and models ,there's no need to make 2 different queries for this task you can combine them into 1.

Comment: There are 3 tables related to question: posts, postWriters and writers.

Comment: @user2356198 if you expect an answer you would need to display them we cant guess the names of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relationship is defined correctly then the fillowing code should work:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('postWriters', function($query) use($arrayOfWriterIds_IFollow) {
    $query->whereIn('writer_id', $arrayOfWriterIds_IFollow);
})
->orderBy('submitTimestamp', 'desc')
->take(20)
->get();
```